# Can multi-buffers have their own etags marks stack?

Tags: linux, emacs, etag

It seems that etags use a global marks stack.

When i open two buffers that use the same TAGS, I performs `find-tags` operations in one buffer(A), then performs `find-tags` operation in the other buffer(B). I switch back to the previous buffer(A) and perform `pop-tag-mark` operation. It will jump back to the mark that is the previous mark of buffer B!

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is completely by design. If you're jumping within a file, `imenu` is more suitable.

Now let's try to modify the design:

```lisp
(defun my-pop-tag-mark (arg)
  "call `pop-tag-mark' without argument.

Pop to the next mark in the current buffer wit C-u prefix."
  (interactive "P")
  (when (consp arg)
    (let ((buf (current-buffer))
          index)
      (loop for marker in (ring-elements find-tag-marker-ring)
            for i from 0 below (ring-length find-tag-marker-ring)
            do (when (eq (setq temp (marker-buffer marker))
                         (current-buffer))
                 (setq index i)
                 (return)))
      (if index
          (ring-insert find-tag-marker-ring (ring-remove find-tag-marker-ring index))
        (error "no marker found in current buffer."))))
  (pop-tag-mark))
```